# How add attributes in custome tab in product edit in magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom tab "Customizer Settings" in edit product in magento admin, I want add hidden attributes in this tab. I have tried below code.

**Config.XML** file

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <productcustomizer_save_product_data>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>saveProductTabData</method>
            </productcustomizer_save_product_data>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
```

and

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab" >
            <name>productcustomizer_settings</name>
            <block>productcustomizer/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

**sql/productcustomizer_setup/install-1.0.0.php** file

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'productcustomizer', array(
    'entity_model' => 'catalog/product',
    'label' => 'custom',
    'group' => 'productcustomizer_settings',
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'text',
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
    'backend' => 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_price',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => false,
    'apply_to' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    #'note' => ''
));
```

It is created new tab "productcustomizer_settings" in product edit.

And also, I have checked after cleared cache and reindex.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a custom template for your tab's block and output a hidden  tag.

In the 'productcustomizer/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab' block's construct method run:

```
/**
 * Set the template for the block
 *
 */
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->setTemplate('productcustomizer/catalog/product/tab.phtml');
}
```

Then, in the template file (productcustomizer/catalog/product/tab.phtml) output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="attribute_name" value="attribute_value" />
```

You must then use an observer to save this attribute_value appropriately on product save. Also, if you just want uneditable attributes you could use the standard attribute group functionality.